# Indexes in MySQL (Unique, Write Statement)

Tags: mysql

I Have 2 Question

1. If my table contain a unique column like this:

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable;
>   CREATE TABLE TestTable(
>   ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>  
>   GUID VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE NULL);

Do i Need to create an Index for this GUID column.
 
Note: i have GUID column In Where statement with join tables

**My Second Question** is the update statement will effect the index table if the updated column(s) not have been indexes?

Comment: ok, edited the answer to address the second question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which database you are using. Different databases have different ways of indexing.

If you are using InnoDB then the Primary Key and Unique Key is already an index, so you won't need to. If you create manually yet another index for the GUID column then you will have an extra redundant index on that column which wastes space.

Answer (score 3):

No, UNIQUE is kind of index, so you don't need another index on the same column.

It won't update the index, if the changed column is not indexed.

> Indexes that are not changed do not get updated.
>   [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update-speed.html)

Comment: +1 More properly worded, all known databases use a unique index to enforce a unique constraint.